# Broadcasts Sent In Quick Succession Cause Issue With Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android

I am having a weird issue with my SMS Broadcast Receiver. When a user sends multiple sms in quick succession, the Broadcast Receivers intent is sent with the most recent info both times.

So for example:

```
User sends SMS ID 2
User sends SMS ID 3
```

The receiver gets:

```
Mark ID 3 as Read
Mark ID 3 as Read
```

Here is the code of my SMS:

```
for (ignored in parts) {
        sentReceivers.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, mId.toInt(), Intent(this, SmsSentBroadcast::class.java)
                .putExtra("message_uri", messageUri.toString()).putExtra("message_id", mId), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))

        if (delivery)
            deliverReceivers!!.add(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, mId.toInt(), Intent(this, SmsDeliverBroadcast::class.java).putExtra("message_uri", messageUri.toString()).putExtra("message_id", mId), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
    }

    smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(address, null, parts, sentReceivers, deliverReceivers)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that `mId.toInt()` was in some cases not unique, so the `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` was overwriting it.

Now that `mId.toInt()` is unique everytime, the Broadcast works as expected